# asio underlying behavior in async_receive

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, asio

I have worked with asio library for a few projects and have always managed to get it work, but I feel there are somethings of it that I have not entirely/clearly understood so far.
I am wondering how `async_receive` works.

I googled around a bit and had a look at the implementation but didn't understand it quite well. This is the way that I often use async communication:

```c++
socket.async_receive(receive_buffer, receiveHandler);
```

where `receiveHandler` is the function that will be called upon the arrival of data on the socket.
I know that the `async_receive` call return immediately. So here are my questions:

1. Does `async_receive` create a new thread each time it is called?
   If not, does it mean that there is a thread responsible to waiting for data and when it arrives, it calls the handler function? When does this thread get created?
2. If I were to turn this call into a recursive call by using a lambda function like this:

```c++
void cyclicReceive() {
  // Imagine the whole thing is in a class, so "this" means something here and
  // "receiveHandler" is still a valid function that gets called.
  socket.async_receive(receive_buffer,
    [this](const asio::error_code& error_code, const std::size_t num_bytes) 
    {
       receiveHandler(error_code, num_bytes);
       cyclicReceive();
    });
}
```

is there any danger of stack overflow? Why not?

I tried to show a minimal example by removing unnecessary details, so the exact syntax might be a bit wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Asio does not create implicitly any new threads. In general it is based on queue of commands. When you call `io.run()` the framework is taking the commands from the queue and executing them until queue is empty. All the `async_` operations in ASIO push new commands to the internal queue.
2. Therefore there is no risk of stack overflow. Worst possible but not really probable scenario is `out_of_memory` exception when there is no space left for commands in command queue (which is very unlikely).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That clarifies much. I guess underneath it still has to call a blocking `recv` then? Would this OOM then happen if one receive stayed blocked and we keep on pushing to the queue?

Comment: @Keivan AFAIK `async_receive` uses nonblocking sockets and the `receive` uses blocking one. Of course, if one pushes too much into the queue and `recv`s keeps to be re-scheduled OOM may happen (though I don't thinks it is very likely scenario considering modern ammounts of memory)

Comment: Yes true. I got the part about the likelihood of it being quite low. Thanks again.